# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am just learning angularjs, with the following code I have been getting this error ==> Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Here is the code, what is going wrong here?

```
    <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <title>js</title>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-       resource.min.js">
    </script>


    </head>

    <body ng-app = "myApp">

         <div ng-controller="SpicyController">
         <button ng-click="chiliSpicy()">Chili</button>
         <button ng-click="jalapenoSpicy()">Jalapeño</button>
         <p>The food is {{spice}} spicy!</p>
   </div>

          <script>

                var myApp = angular.module('spicyApp1', []);

          myApp.controller('SpicyController', function($scope) {
            $scope.spice = 'very';

          $scope.chiliSpicy = function() {
                $scope.spice = 'chili';
          };

          $scope.jalapenoSpicy = function() {
                $scope.spice = 'jalapeño';
          };
          });

          </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You are using two old version `1.0.4`..I will recommend you to use newer one to get benifite of more feature and bug free Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your app name, Since you are defining the module as **`spicyApp1`**

**From:**

```
<body ng-app = "myApp">
```

**To**

```
 <body ng-app = "spicyApp1">
```

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/nyML3WjqaCQq58Wss3rF?p=preview)

Comment: I see, thanks for that! Very unusual  how it's not working on chrome